# Update page after query python flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm having some problems in coding. I've to add a question in a forum in Python. After adding new objects in the db, the code print just the old objects, without the new one, even if in the db the object is added.
The new objects are printed only if I run again.

```
@app.route('/question/<topic_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newquestion(topic_id):
    username = 'elena27'  
    question_ = request.form['question']
    new_question = applicativo.newQuestion(username, question_, topic_id)
    db.session.add(new_question)
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.remove()
    return render_template('newquestion.html')
```

Here is applicativo.py:

```
def countQuestion():
    number=int(session.query(Question).order_by('-id').first().id)
    return number+1

def newQuestion(username, question, topic):
    id = countQuestion()
    date = datetime.now()
    question = Question(id, topic, username, question, date)
    return question
```

question.html:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action={{ url_for('newquestion', topic_id=topic_id) }}>
    <p>
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    </p>
</form>
```

newquestion.html page is just a static page.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: should you not be passing in all of the Questions to the `render_template()` method?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I Have a Hunch you are using MySQL.

By Default, MySQL uses an **Isolation Level** of `Repeatable Read`.

Repeatable read essentially means that any data read cannot change, if the transaction reads the same data again, it will find the previously read data in place, unchanged.

What you want is `READ COMMITTED`

This essentially restricts the reader from seeing any intermediate, uncommitted, 'dirty' data. It always reads the current commits, and makes no promises of consistency.

There are others such as `READ UNCOMMITTED` and `SERIALIZABLE`

Pass an **isolation level** argument to your session constructor..

For `Flask-SQLAlchemy` I believe

`db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={"isolation_level":"READ COMMITED"})`

should work, but I dont use `FLask-SQLAlchemy`

for raw `SQLAlchemy` Engine

`eng = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://admin:password@localhost/example",
    isolation_level='READ COMMITTED')`

for more on Isolation Levels and SQLAlchemy, (engine level, connection level, transaction level)

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels